# Was Alex Jones alone in the RV when it was parked infront of his old home?

Tags: plot-explanation, prisoners

If he was alone, why did he randomly park it in front of old home? If he remembers it to be once his home, then why could he not make an effort to reach out his parents? Considering his 10 year boy brain, i doubt if he remembers it though.

The other case is that  Mrs. Jones was with him in the RV. In such a case, was bringing him there a ritual to soothe Alex?